# Connect to SAP system using JCo through a SAPRouter

Tags: java, jco

I've been trying to connect a java program to SAP using JCo Java connectors (latest version 3.0.13).

I was having trouble and I was told that the problem was that I was trying to connect directly and I need to connect via saprouter.

There's a connection property called saprouter where I need to place the SAP router string.

I've only found the way to specify such string for JCo (version 2.xx) and it is:

```
/H/<saprouter>/H/<hostname>
```

Is this the same for JCo in its latest version? If so, the specification of connection properties will be done well like this?

```
    Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "xx.xx.x.xx");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR,  "00");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "020");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER,   "xxxxx");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "xxxxxx");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG,   "en");
    connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SAPROUTER,   "/H/<saprouter>/H/<hostname>");
```

Comment: Please do not create a second question unnecessarily - this is clearly a follow-up of your first (incomplete) question.

Comment: Also, please at least add a link when [cross-posting the same question on other sites](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3768139)